# How to redirect to IDP URL

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2, spring-saml

I am very new to spring saml trying to implement SSO using simple saml in spring boot application.

I am not able to redirect to IDP URL.

I am using java configuration.

Following is my code.

```
// Setup advanced info about metadata
@Bean
public ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata() {
    ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata = new ExtendedMetadata();
    //extendedMetadata.setAlias("gppalias");
    extendedMetadata.setIdpDiscoveryEnabled(true); 
    extendedMetadata.setSignMetadata(false);
    // I guess here we need to put IDP url ... 
    extendedMetadata.setIdpDiscoveryURL("https:urlof idp");
    //extendedMetadata.setIdpDiscoveryResponseURL("localhost:8080");
    return extendedMetadata;
}
```

Also I need to skip port in 443 metadata generation.

Please guide me in this regard

Thanks & Regards
Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

Inside you application, you should just configure the metadata reader. The IdP URL is defined inside them.

For instance, by looking for the metadata provided by *SSOCircle*, you can find as location of the `SingleSignOnService` the redirection endpoint and the related binding protocol, as follows:

```
<SingleSignOnService Location="https://idp.ssocircle.com:443/sso/SSORedirect/metaAlias/ssocircle" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"/>
```

For a practical example, you can give a look at this sample configuration file for **Spring SAML**: **[spring-boot-security-saml-sample  > WebSecurityConfig.java](https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vdenotaris/spring/boot/security/saml/web/config/WebSecurityConfig.java#L276)**